# How to match only the first occurrence of an alphanumeric character, preceded by a non-alphanumeric character?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I construct a regular expression to yield the index of an *alphanumeric* character that is **preceded** by a *non-alphanumeric* character?

**Examples:**

1. (Special Edition) --> should match only 'S' and yield an index of 1
2. Special Edition --> should not match at all
3. "{(Special Edition)}" --> should match 'S' and yield an index of 3

I know that JavaScript can provide the index of the match like so:

```
const index = string.match(/regular_expression/)?.index || 0;
```

I cannot figure out how to construct the an expression that does what I have described.

Comment: Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/HIi4Uo/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use positive lookbehind and `String.prototype.search` method:

```
'(Special Edition)'.search(/(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9\s])[A-Za-z0-9]/); // 1

'Special Edition'.search(/(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9\s])[A-Za-z0-9]/); // -1

'{(Special Edition)}'.search(/(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9\s])[A-Za-z0-9]/); // 2
```

Comment: Thank you! This does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If this part `(S` should yield index 1, I think this part `{(S` should yield index 2 instead of 3.

You can match both characters and capture the second character using a capture group, and then add 1 to get the index.

You can use a lookbehind assertion if that [is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) and then you don't need the extra addition of 1.

As a pattern you can match:

```
[^a-zA-Z\d\s]([a-zA-Z\d])
```

The pattern matches:

- `[^a-zA-Z\d\s]` Match a single char not being alphanumeric or a whitespace char
- `([a-zA-Z\d])` Capture a single alphanumeric char in group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AvZsIK/1).

```js
const regex = /[^a-zA-Z\d\s]([a-zA-Z\d])/;

[
  "(Special Edition)",
  "Special Edition",
  "{(Special Edition)}",
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(`${s} --> ${m[1]} index: ${m.index + 1}`);
  }
})
```

Comment: Sorry. I should have clarified that the quotation marks were part of the string content.

Comment: Your solution seems to work. However, it also matches the preceding non-alphanumeric character, which is why you have to increment the index by 1. Is there a way to avoid incrementing the index and just match directly on the alphanumeric character?

Comment: @MihkelPajunen I have updated the answer to use a capture group.

Comment: @MihkelPajunen In that case you can use the same pattern with a lookbehind assertion. Note that it should be [supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)